When I Import FBX animation to unity it says there is no animation data
 This is a picture of my settings. I can't apply transforms because then they shrink to their origins even when I don't use scale to individual origins.
Even when I bake keyframes. I don't know why but for some reason I key-framed transforms and custom properties. The scale seems to be 1. I did try changing it to FBX unit scale. I even tried to unapply unit.
When I leave the bake option in the image checked it buffers and crashes. I checked my Ram 3GB of 4GB. It would not open in FBX opener. I have other Fbx animations of the same character that do work but unity doesn't use the entire animation only 87.5%
 This is Unity showing there is no data.
 Only 0.875 maximum. I cannot increase this to 100%. It happens with all. I tried adding a keyframe at the start at end and not baking, making sure it started at 0. Baking keyframes.

This could be an issue on the Blender end of exporting but mostly has to do with some setting between Unity and Blender itself. This forum is best for questions specifically pertaining to how to use Blender.
